# How to change web sphere settings in RAD Administrative console

Tags: java

I have web sphere server integrated to RAD(rational application developer).When i stop the server from the server view,I can see the server stopped but when start it again the server does not start many times, since the java process still runs I can see that in the task manager. so i have to go to task manager and have to kill the java process and restart my Rad and have to stop the server again. 
I know we can change the server settings in Administrative console to stop the server when ever we close the work space etc.But i could not find where exactly it is.

Please help me where and how we can change these settings in administrative console

Answer (score 2):

Double-Click on your server (in your server view) to open your server overview.

Click on Terminate server on workbench shutdown.

Edit the Screenshot[image: Server Overview]

Comment: Thanks,it works fine when i close the workspace and start the server again.But When I connect to the network after disconnecting or comes back from the standby mode, In both cases earlier the server was running,I cant see the server running from the server view but the server runs internally,Y it happens?